# Why does Google Books API not return a complete response?

Tags: reactjs, google-books-api

I made a request to google books API, trying to retrieve the volumes (a.k.a books) from my bookshelf. But the response I get contains only 10 items whereas on the shelf I have 17 items.

Could this be that my code is faulty, or maybe a restriction from google ?
see my code for making the call and for mapping it.

My api.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import request from 'superagent';
import BookList from './BookList';

class Book extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        books: [],
      }
    }
     componentDidMount(){
       request.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/101###############/bookshelves/4/volumes?key=AIzaSyDNMnPGw3################-PecbhU")
      .query(null)
      .then((data) =>{
       console.log(data);
        this.setState({books: [...data.body.items]})
        
      })
    
    }
   
   

    render(){
      
      return(
        <div>
              <BookList books={this.state.books}/>
              
        </div>
  
  
      );
    }
    

  }

  export default Book
```

And here i map

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import BookCard from './bookcard';

const BookList = (props) => {
    if(!props){
        return null;
    }
    return(
       <div>
            {
                props && props.books?.map((book, i) => {
                    return <div class="grid-container">
                    <BookCard
                    key={i}
                        image={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}
                        title={book.volumeInfo.title}
                        author={book.volumeInfo.authors}
                        url={book.volumeInfo.canonicalVolumeLink}
                        rating={book.volumeInfo.averageRating}
                    
                    />
                    </div>
                    
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

 export default BookList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs say](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using):

> **Pagination**
>
> You can paginate the volumes list by specifying two values in the parameters for the request:
>
> startIndex - The position in the collection at which to start. The index of the first item is 0.
>
> maxResults - The maximum number of results to return. **The default is 10**, and the maximum allowable value is 40.

So you can add `maxResults=40` to your query to get more results at once.

Comment: Thanks, Lad i must have skipped that part of the docs